# Can I trust (uintptr_t)NULL to be equal to zero?

Tags: c, pointers, null

I know that `NULL` is not required to be an all bits zero pattern. But I do wonder if

```
uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)NULL;
printf("%" PRIuPTR, x);
```

is guaranteed to print `0`? I suspect it's not, but just want to be sure.

Or more to the point. Can I trust this?

```
if( ((uintptr_t)f(x) | (uintptr_t)f(y)) != 0)
```

Assume `f` is a function returning a pointer. I suspect that this piece of code heavily relies on that `NULL` is an all bit zero pattern. Am I correct?

I know it's considered bad practice, and I would never write something like that myself, but I wonder if it's well defined.

I stumbled upon this piece of code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65990247/6699433) where the author is using

```
while ( ( (uintptr_t)fgets(a,100,fp1) | (uintptr_t)fgets (b,100,fp) ) != 0 ) {
        printf("%s",a);
        printf("%s",b);
}
```

Comment: Not meaning to drift off target here, but any reason not to just `if (f(x) || f(y))` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, that's ONE of my questions to the author of that piece of code ;)

Comment: @WhozCraig Perhaps the code wanted to avoid short circuiting the second function call, but that can still be done without the `(uintptr_t)` hackery.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, that's true. But the loop body contains unconditional printouts of both `a` and `b` ;)

Comment: Maybe some compiler from 1979 may use NULL as something different from 0, but I don't think any new C compiler will take the risk to define it as `~0` (for example). And break thousands of programs.

Comment: @i486 Sure, but since you're the author of the code, can you explain the purpose of casting to `uintptr_t` in the first place?

Comment: @i486 The problem is not the definition of `NULL` which ought to be a valid _null pointer constant_ such as `0` or `((void*)0)`. The problem is that there is no requirement for the  internal representation of a _null pointer_ to be all-bits zero, and no requirement for the conversion of a null pointer to an integral type to produce the value 0.

Comment: I think the opposite is true: if `(uintptr)some_valid_non_null_pointer != 0`.

Comment: It is unclear why terser, less problematic  `while (!!fgets(a,100,fp1) | !!fgets (b,100,fp)) ` was not offered instead. It avoids the optional aspect of `uintptr_t` and conversion issues.

Answer (score 3):

In theory: no.

In practice: probably.

In the relevant standardese, the checks for null pointers are "special" in the sense that they are not numeric comparisons with the value zero, so in theory, some implementation or platform could assign a different value to null pointers.

Comment: Note that a  _null pointer_, even of all zero bits, is not specified to convert to an integer with the value of 0.  Likely only on a hostile compiler or one designed to expose code weaknesses.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's a very good point. Good enough to include in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not such a guarantee. As per 7.19 NULL is macrodefinition which expands to implementation defined null pointer  constant.

But `if(p)` is guaranteed to be the truth if the `p` is not NULL (where `p` is a pointer).

So `printf("%d\n", !!p)` is guaranteed to print `0` if pointer is NULL and `1` if not

```
while ( fgets(a,100,fp1) || fgets (b,100,fp))
```

or

```
while ( fgets(a,100,fp1) != NULL || fgets (b,100,fp) != NULL)
```

or a bit more pervert way

```
while ( ((fgets(a,100,fp1) != NULL) | (fgets (b,100,fp) != NULL)) != 0)
```

```
while ( (!!fgets(a,100,fp1) | !!fgets (b,100,fp)) != 0)
```

Comment: Or more specifically, it expands to an implementation defined null pointer constant (not that there are any other kinds of pointer constant!).

Comment: @IanAbbott indeed, amemnded . Some parts of the standard are actually written like after a long night of controlled substances smoking :)

Answer (score 1):

> But I do wonder if (below) is guaranteed to print 0?

```
uintptr_t x = (uintptr_t)NULL;
printf("%" PRIuPTR, x);
```

No.  It commonly does, but not *specified* to do so.

- `(uintptr)NULL` simply is not *specified* to convert to 0.  It is fairly common  practice to do so though.  `NULL` may be an integer or a pointer. `NULL` may be a pointer that does not convert to an integer 0.  Even if `NULL` is an all zeros bits pattern, it is still not specified to convert to an integer 0.
- `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` are optional types.  They often exist, but are not required.  Consider a system with `void *` wider than 64-bit, yet the widest  integer type is 64-bit.

---

> Can I trust this?

```
if( ((uintptr_t)f(x) | (uintptr_t)f(y)) != 0)
```

It will commonly work, but it is not highly portable.
Alternative:

```
if( !!f(x) | !!f(y))
```

> I suspect that this piece of code heavily relies on that NULL is an all bit zero pattern. Am I correct?

Almost.  It relies on `(uintptr_t)NULL` converting to 0.

---

In addition to conversion concerns, I find a weakness in the below code concerning `fgets()` returning `NULL` due to an input error or end-of-file.

Should `fgets(a,100,fp1)` return `NULL` due to end-of-file, the buffer is not certainly _null character terminated either (it might be stale too) - leading to more UB or old output in printing.

If an input error occurred, (wrong stream direction, file not open, etc.), then `a[]` is indeterminate leading to UB with `printf("%s",a);`

```
while ( ( (uintptr_t)fgets(a,100,fp1) | (uintptr_t)fgets (b,100,fp) ) != 0 ) {
    printf("%s",a);
    printf("%s",b);
}
```

The buffer contents of `fgets()` are best not read when the function returns `NULL`.